Port repository with reprepro
I'm trying to set up a repository for a Debian port, using reprepro. The following things should happen:

source packages and Architecture: all binary packages should be imported
port-specific binary packages should be added to the repository through an incoming/ directory
updated source packages should be imported
removed source packages should be removed, along with binaries generated from them
port-specific binaries should be kept except if their source package has been removed completely

So far, I've managed to do 1-3, with a simple Update: rule that pulls from amd64, with
Architectures: amd64>riscv64 source
FilterFormula: Architecture (== all) | $PackageType (== dsc)

Adding a - to the Update: adds removal of removed packages, but also removes all my port-specific packages that have a different binary version number in the port (due to rebuilds) than they have in the main archive.
Is there a way to mark existing binary packages for deletion only if the source package they refer to (which may have a different version) has been deleted or superseded in the repository being pulled from, and is only kept locally because of the reference from the binary packages?
